# Deleted files are 'restored' when doing an update with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I delete a file from my working copy, then do an Update, the deleted file is restored.

This is quite annoying, because I then have to go find the file and delete it again.

I'm not sure why SVN does this. If I want to do an Update, it means I want to pull down any changes from the respository. It doesn't mean I want to restore files that I have deleted.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: I don't know if it counts as a workaround, but "using git" solves the problem. This behaviour, IMHO and looking at the answers, is just plain wrong. I am expected to perform an update before committing, but if I do, files I deleted are restored and files I moved around are duplicated. This kinda sucks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to delete the file from SVN, you need to do an SVN delete, not just delete the file locally. SVN delete is in the TortoiseSVN context submenu.

Comment: is there maybe a feature to warn us about the restoring, maybe allow us to make it do SVN-delete before the update starts?

Comment: What if I want a file to be and stay deleted in my local work directory but not to delete it in the repository and also want to pull in all changes from the server? How do I avoid SVN automatically restoring the deleted files? (Not a theoretical question, as I am just facing exactly that situation. :) )

Answer (score 1):

To mitigate after the problem occurs, i do this:

1. Select all the rows in tortoise svn window that were 'Restored',
   and copy
2. Paste in second column of a new excel sheet
3. in first column, type: del "
4. fill the column with del " next to the restored files' paths, by double clicking bottom right corner of the first cell in which you typed del "
5. fill after each path with a closing "
6. Win+R (Start -> Run) notepad -> Enter. Copy all and paste into notepad. Select and copy one tab, Ctrl + H, replace all, replaces tabs with nothing to remove tabs
7. Win+R cmd -> Enter , right click and paste the delete commands in command line, press enter and the files get deleted

I know these are a long list of instructions, but I believe they should be second nature to developers, and are necessary to know and go about quickly, for multiple purposes beyond this one, using excel this way, creating and running batch commands quickly, etc...