# Prevent deleted file/folder recreation in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I want to delete a file/folder I can do so locally and commit the changes. However, when another user runs an SVN update the deleted files/folder don't delete on their local copy.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i've found the answer;

I needed to select "delete" from the tortoise SVN context menu rather than just doing a windows delete. When i committed and did an SVN update on another machine the delete replicated correctly. This seems bonkers :/

[Deleted files are 'restored' when doing an update with TortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865902/deleted-files-are-restored-when-doing-an-update-with-tortoisesvn)

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html

Comment: It's not "bonkers", it's exactly how Subversion is designed to work (and I'm fairly sure it's documented in the manuals). Subversion doesn't do things (like delete items from the repository) unless you explicitly tell it to do them.

Comment: But I am explicitly telling it to delete them. When I commit it shows the delete operations and I tick them to confirm I want those delete operations to be committed?

Comment: @LeeTickett is it still reproducible? could you please show us a screenshot?

Comment: Oddly it's behaving differently now. But the folder I successfully managed to delete using the tortoise context menu is now appearing when I try and commit saying "missing". Very confused.

Comment: Windows delete != SVN Delete. You were originally performing a Windows delete, which does *not* tell SVN to delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you and the other developer work on different branches. The expected behavior is that the deleted item will be deleted from your colleague's working copy on the next `svn update`.

Run [`svn info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) in your and your colleague's working copy and see whether the URL is the same or not.